# Monogame with VS 2012 on Windows 7

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, monogame

I have taken game programming class for which I have to make a basic project using  template "MonoGame Windows Store (XAML) Project"

We are provided Virtual client wihch has windows 8 and all the tools installed but I cant access it right now for some reason.

I have Windows 7 on my system with Visual Studio 2012 and Monogame 3 installed. I checked my template folder I have all these templates: [image: Templates in my ProjectTemplates folder.]

However I can only see following templates in my VS 2012:
[image: Templates in Visual Studio 2012.]

I have tried restarting the machine but it shows the same templates. The template i need i cant see here.

Is this because I am using Windows 7?

Is there any way I can make XAML project on my Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, Windows Store Apps can only be developed (and run) on Windows 8 or higher, so no, it will *not* work on Windows 7.

Comment: Crap .. dats what I was worried abt .. 
Thanks For confirming :)